# What single word means "uncritique-able"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I'm looking for a single word be for unable to be critiqued - "uncritique-able" - as in - "some people would say that the bible is "uncritique-able." I want the word to convey that one *should not* critique it, rather than that there is nothing worthy of being critiqued.

Not merely sacred, but something more specific.

Comment: Uncriticisable:  that cannot be criticised.

Comment: That would be a *sacredcow*.

Comment: 'Authoritative' and 'inerrant' are used when referring to say the Bible. But not by all.

Comment: I think that the concept is sufficiently nuanced that a single word is inevitably going to be insufficient.

Answer (score 13):

**Sacrosanct**: above or beyond criticism, change, or interference. ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sacrosanct))

This is an apt term for anything considered religious, and is derived from the Latin *sacrosanctus*: "protected by religious sanction, consecrated with religious ceremonies" ([Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sacrosanct)). It has become a more generic and secular word that carries the meaning given above.

Answer (score 2):

Unassailable.

Not able to be attacked or refuted.

It conveys less judgment of value than "sacred" but more that it's been proven good or correct.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unassailable

Answer (score 1):

Irreproachable

beyond criticism; faultless:

Comment: read the question again

Answer (score 1):

Something that cannot be critiqued is ***[indisputable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/indisputable)***.

> Unable to be challenged or denied: *a far from indisputable fact*

Answer (score 1):

[Gospel](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gospel)

accepted or promoted as infallible truth or as a guiding principle or doctrine

Comment: A citation for this legitimate answer?

Comment: @ScotM - thanks for pointing that out, link is added now... though I still can't really distinguish links with the default css settings.

Answer (score 0):

Infallible

absolutely trustworthy or sure

Through my own experience, I believe this word carries the undertone that something's trustworthiness should not even be questioned.

Answer (score 0):

### Axiomatic

From the [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/axiomatic):

> Self-evident or unquestionable: 'it is *axiomatic* that dividends have to be financed'

Answer (score -2):

Flawless

'That diamond is flawless'